# Arizona criminal traffic law

Tags: criminal-law, traffic, arizona

Suppose that a person Bob  was ticketed for criminal aggressive driving in 1/2021, at 87 mph in a 75 mph zone.

Arizona passed an amendment to the law in 6/2021 so that a person must  be going over 20 mph of posted speed limit for this law to apply. What happens to Bob's charge? Can it be canceled because of the later change in the law?

Answer (score 2):

The 20mph+ exemption is only applicable in certain circumstances (*see sub-section (2),  below*) and is not relevant here as it appears the driver breached [Title 18, §28-701.02(A)(3)](https://law.justia.com/codes/arizona/2020/title-28/section-28-701-02/):

> **A. A person shall not:**
>
> 1. Exceed thirty-five miles per hour approaching a school crossing.
> 2. Exceed the posted speed limit in a business or residential district by more than twenty miles per hour, or if no speed limit is posted, exceed forty-five miles per hour.
>
> **3. Exceed eighty-five miles per hour in other locations.**

So it seems the ticket is valid.

Comment: Even if the exemption was relevant, the offense was committed before the law changed so the legacy statute would still apply to the offense.

Comment: No grandfathering works both ways. Just like how the government can't decide something is illegal, and then charge you with having done it in the past, if something does become legal, those already charged are not automatically rendered innocent. Just look at the marijuana situation...

Answer (score 2):

### Nothing

You broke the law as it was at the time and were validly sanctioned. It doesn’t matter what the law was or is at another time.